# Prove using elementary methods: $|\sin(x) - \sin(y)|\le |x-y|$

Tags: trigonometry

> For arbitrary $x$ and $y$: $$|\sin(x) - \sin(y)|\le |x-y|$$

Hints are appreciated more than complete solutions. No calculus or theory of limits can be used; only elementary methods.

The sine and cosine are defined as Two functions satisfying:

1)$S$  and $C$ are defined  on the entire Real line.

2)Certain special values:1)$C({\pi \over {2}}) = -1 , C(0) = S({\pi \over {2}}) = 1$

3)$C(x-y) = C(x)C(y) + S(x)S(y)$

4)$x \in (0,{\pi \over{2}}): 0 \lt C(x) \lt  {S(x) \over{x}} \lt {1 \over{C(x)}}$

Comment: Some sort of analysis must be involved; even if its buried in an axiomatic statement like "it makes sense to talk about certain kinds of curves, and it makes sense to talk about their length, and a straight line has the shortest length among all curves between two points".

Comment: What is your definition of $\sin(x)$?

Comment: An axiomatic defintion, functions $S$ and $C$ that satisfiy certain axioms.

Comment: @Hurkyl Can you demonstrate why this must be true?

Comment: Just saying that $s^2(x)+c^2(x)=1$ and $s(0)=0$ is not enough to define sine and cosine. It should involve some other relation between $s$ and $c$. Normally, they say that $s'(x) = c(x)$ but you disallowed calculus. To see why it's not enough, note that $f(t)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $g(t)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ satisfy those axioms, obtained by parametrization of the unit circle, but they are not the same as sine and cosine. So, do write down your definition of sine and cosine that you want to use for others to know how you define them. :)

Comment: Yes;There are 4 axioms:1)$S$ and $C$ are defined on the entire  Real line.       2)Certain special values:$C(\pi) = -1,C(0) = S({\pi \over{2}}) =1$             3)$C(y-x) = C(y)C(x) + S(x)S(y) 4) x \in (0,{\pi \over{2}}) : {0} \lt {C(x)}\lt {S(x) \over{x}}\lt {1 \over {C(x)}}$

Comment: @LoganLuther: It's a combination of "I haven't seen it done", and also of knowing about axiomatizations of Euclidean geometry that omit the analysis-type axiom describing how the line has to be a continuum. Without that axiom (or another one of the same sort) you can't prove, for example, that there exists a line segment of length $\pi$. (and I really do mean it *impossible*, not just "nobody has managed it yet")

Comment: @LoganLuther: Your fourth axiom seems to work in combination with Siong's answer, but it looks kind of wrong of me. I'm not sure yet. Are you sure you haven't written it done incorrectly? (please do include your axioms in the question. Your question lacks context as it is now)

Answer (score 7):

This is the simplest way which came in my mind

Hope this can be useful

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: This is very beautiful (and it works) but the OP wants to use an axiomatic definition of sine and cosine. Read the comments.